# Jsp ao invés de Servlet

Tags: aplicação-web, jsp

pesquisei bastante mas não ficou muito claro para mim o seguinte. Porque não posso utilizar paginas JSP para conectar com Banco de Dados (Mysql por exemplo) e retornar estes dados por uma função Ajax por exemplo, para outra pagina JSP que vai exibir os dados? Isso é questão de padronização ou outro motivo? Se eu fizesse um trabalho da faculdade utilizando JSP para consultar o BD seria considerado errado? Mesmo que a aplicação funcione 100%?

Comment: Pesquise sobre o padrão MVC, o aconselhado é que se separe em camadas a sua aplicação onde a camada de visualização (VIEW) não acesse direto o banco de dados.

Comment: Mas eu não posso utilizar uma pagina JSP que faz a consulta na camada Controller e retorna os dados para outra JSP que está dentro da View?